# How do I do a 301 redirect while changing the domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, seo

I'm transferring a site that's hosted on Tumblr to a new Wordpress site. The blog as it is has decent traffic so I need to do a 301 redirect on the pages to the new site. But I also need to use the same domain name on the new site. Is there any way of allowing them both to use the domain name?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowing them both to use the domain name"?

Comment: For example the Tumblr page is redirecting from:
**TheSiteURL.com/posts/9357487/the-page**
to the new site:
**TheSiteURL.com/the-page**
They would have to both be using the same domain name:
**TheSiteURL.com**

Comment: Is there anything in common between the two urls? e.g will the text after "/9357487/" always be the new url?

Comment: Yeah, The last part would be the same e.g. **/the-page**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess file after `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteRule posts/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$2/ [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect urls like "http://example.com/posts/9357487/the-page" to "http://exmaple.com/the-page/".

Comment: Any idea why it will work with 5 letters at the start but not 4?
e.g **RewriteRule posts/([0-9]+)/** works, unlike **RewriteRule post/([0-9]+)/(**

Comment: Because it is matching `posts/somenumbers`. `post/somenumbers` won't match.